# Flutter ClipRRect not working on BackdropFilter while with GoogleMap inside Stack

Tags: flutter, google-maps

### Flutter ClipRRect not working on BackdropFilter with GoogleMap

Flutter ClipRRect not working on BackdropFilter while with GoogleMap inside Stack but working with any other widgets(Image.network and so on)

I tried both master and beta channels but still same result.

```
ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(52),
                    child: BackdropFilter(
                      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 19, sigmaY: 19),
                      child: Container(
                          height: 219,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.39),
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    firstSelecting = true;
                                  });
                                  await getLocation();
                                  final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
                                  controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
                                    target: _currentPosition!,
                                    zoom: 15,
                                  )));
                                  controller.dispose();
                                },
                                child: ListTile(
                                  leading: Container(
                                    height: 34,
                                    width: 34,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(firstSelecting ? 0.79 : 0.49)), shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                    child: Center(
                                        child: Container(
                                      height: 25,
                                      width: 25,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(firstSelecting ? 0.79 : 0.49), shape: BoxShape.circle),
                                      child: const Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "1",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 19),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                  title: Text(
                                    firstPlace,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(firstSelecting ? 0.79 : 0.49), fontSize: 19),
                                  ),
                                  trailing: Icon(
                                    Icons.location_pin,
                                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(firstSelecting ? 0.79 : 0.49),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              
                                    
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bPhK.jpg)

How it looks like